# Why is the value of n equal to 5 in the first iteration?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, assignment-operator

I have a question that why is the value of n being used in the first iteration is 5 and not 6. I checked it on stackeoverflow and there many of them said that in the first iteration the value of n is used and then it is decreased by 1 and used in the next iteration.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int ans = 1, n = 6;

    while (n--)
    {
        printf("n = %d\n", n);

        if (n != 0)
        {
            ans *= n;
        }
    }

    printf("ans = %d", ans);

    return 0;
}



Output:
n = 5
n = 4
n = 3
n = 2
n = 1
n = 0
ans = 120
```

Comment: `n--` will decrement the value from 6 to 5. That runs before the `printf` so `5` will be printed.

Comment: Read this: [C increment/decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec)

Comment: "*many of them said that in the first iteration the value of n is used and then it is decreased by 1*". I think you are misunderstanding that. Indeed `n` is used before it is decremented but only for the `while` statement. Everything after that will see the decremented value.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 6;
while (n--) {
    // n is 5, then 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, then the while terminates
}
// n is -1
```

compare with

```
n = 6;
while (--n) {
    // n is 5, then 4, 3, 2, 1, then the while terminates
}
// n is 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`while (n--)`

1. `while` checks if `n` is non zero. (`n == 6`)
2. `n` is being decremented. (`n == 5`)
3. Body of the while is executed. (5 is being printed)

To multiple from `6` you need to use `do ... while` loop

```
int main(void)
{
    int ans = 1, n = 6;

    do
    {
        printf("n = %d\n", n);
        ans *= n ? n : 1;
    }while (n--);

    printf("ans = %d", ans);

    return 0;
}
```

or

```
    while(n)
    {
        printf("n = %d\n", n);
        ans *= n;  // note you do not need to check if n != 0
        n--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
int n, x;
```

| Post-decrement: | Same as: |
| --- | --- |
| `n = 6;` | `n = 6;` |
| `x = n--;` | `x = n;` |
|  | `n = n - 1;` |

Which results in `x == 6` and `n == 5`.

---

| Pre-decrement: | Same as: |
| --- | --- |
| `n = 6;` | `n = 6;` |
| `x = --n;` | `n = n - 1;` |
|  | `x = n;` |

Which results in `x == 5`, and again, `n == 5`.

---

So, what pre- and post-decrement have in common is that the value of `n` is decreased by one, which is why you do not see `6` inside the loop.

If you want to loop from `6` to `1` (inclusive), it's simpler to use a `for`-loop:

```
for(n = 6; n; --n) {
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    ans *= n;
}
```

which is similar to

```
n = 6;
while(n) {
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    ans *= n;
    --n;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer lies in the post decrement operator. Every time `while (n--)` is encountered, the value of n remains `n` and not `n-1` as expected from the post decrement operator `--`.

```
while (n--) { // At first, n is 6 for this statement
    // n is 5 then 4, 3, 2, 1
}
```

On the same note,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i--) {
    // Some code
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; --i) {
    // Some code
}
```

have same values of i.